# Unable to set bounds for AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a hard time changing the bounds of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. Whatever I do it always ends up in small size as shown below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.imageLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 100)
    }

    private func startLiveVideo() {

        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

        let deviceInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
        let deviceOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        deviceOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
        deviceOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default))
        session.addInput(deviceInput)
        session.addOutput(deviceOutput)

        self.imageLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 100)
        self.imageView.layer.addSublayer(self.imageLayer)

        session.startRunning()
    }
```

SOLUTION:

```
self.imageLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
```

Comment: I just posted a solution in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can first assign width and height of **imageView** from Storyboard or by **yourViewController** 500 x 500 or whatsoever size you want.

```
imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.imageView.frame.width, height: self.imageView.frame.height)

self.imageView.layer.addSublayer(self.imageLayer)
```